# Generating Dynamic bootstrap Menus with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create bootstrap navbar menus dynamically using Angular.

The source data for the menu comes from json which looks like below:

```
{   
"Menu": [
    {
        "title": "Individual",
        "url": "#",
        "subMenu": [{
            "title": "Individual Address",
            "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp",
            "subMenu": []
          }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Organisation",
        "url": "#",
        "subMenu": [{
            "title": "Organisation Address",
            "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp",
            "subMenu": []
        },{
            "title": "Organisation Contact",
            "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp",
            "subMenu": []
        },{
            "title": "Organisation Sector",
            "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp",
            "subMenu": []
        }]
    },

    {
        "title": "Return",
        "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp",
        "subMenu": []
    }
]
}
```

As you can see that there are nested items so we need to have dropdown menus in our navigation bar.

I have created a directive to generate the dynamic menus (I have used the directive found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KNM4q/113/) as a starting point). The modified version of the directive looks like:

```
app.directive('tree', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        scope: { val: '=', parentData:'=' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          if (scope.val.subMenu !== undefined && scope.val.subMenu.length > 0) {
                template =      '<li class="dropdown"> '+
                              '  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{val.url}}">{{val.title}} '+
                              '  <span class="caret"></span></a> '+
                              '  <ul class="dropdown-menu"> '+
                              '   <div ng-repeat="item in val.subMenu"> '+
                              '     <tree val="item" parent-data="val.subMenu"></tree> '+
                              '   </div>'
                              '  </ul> '+
                              '</li> ';
            }
            else
            {
              template = '<li><a href="{{val.url}}">{{val.title}}</a></i> ';
            }
            var newElement = angular.element(template);
            $compile(newElement)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(newElement);            
        }
    }
```

Below is the html code where I am using this directive

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <div ng-repeat="menu in menuFamily.Menu">
            <tree val="menu"></tree>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

The menus are generated but because I am using `div` tags for `ng-repeat`, the menus are not rendered properly. However, if I remove the `div` tags from the generated html everything works fine. So my question how can I achieve what I want without using `div` tags.

You can also find my sample code at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hp89k4js18PJ8ckwuYCk)

P.S. I am new to Angular world and I have a very basic knowledge of directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there are two things you need to do:

### Correct usage of `ng-repeat`

`ng-repeat` can be applied directly to your `tree` directive. Change

```
<div ng-repeat="...">
    <tree ...>
</div>
```

To

```
<tree ng-repeat="..." />
```

Both in your html file and in your directive's `template` property.

This will apply the proper styles to your menu.

### Import Bootstrap `js` and initialize dropdowns

<strike>Because Angular will modify the DOM to add your dropdown's HTML, you need to manually initialize the dropdowns once they have been added.</strike>

Call `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` once your elements have been added.

Nevermind, just add the Bootstrap JS in your page, seems it properly initializes by itself.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" data-semver="2.1.4" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Editied plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLjP2LsRuclIke1E8Yzy).